# jQuery, Select Body but exclude Textarea and Input:Text, how?

Tags: jquery, selector

I tried this `$('body').children().not('textarea input:text')`
But not working. Anyone has an idea?

I want this because when I use [jQuery.translator](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-translate/), I do not want the `textarea` and `input:text` get transalted, so I like to exclude them. If you know a better way to do this, let me know. Thanks.

**EDIT**

I think I asked a wrong question, please check here for new question
[Do NOT translate textarea by jQuery.translator, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631134/do-not-translate-textarea-by-jquery-translator-how)

I am going to close this one now. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('body *:not(textarea, input:text)')
```

`children()` only gives you the immediate children, and it's unlikely you have input elements directly under `body` without some kind of structure intervening. Also, `'textarea input:text'` means text inputs that are *within* a textarea, which will (hopefully) never happen.

Comment: I tried this one, not working. I guess the problem maybe not at the selector, maybe is because the jQuery.translate. Thanks anyway

Comment: Try just the selector in console, to see what you're getting.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('*:not(textarea,:text)', document.body);
```

Comment: thanks. This looks good but still not working, maybe the problem just as what I comment above. I will start a new question to ask it. Thanks anyway

Comment: It should work, but I added the body context since you probably don’t want to translate stuff in the head: http://jsfiddle.net/bEmnj/