# Do NOT translate textarea by jQuery.translator, how?

Tags: jquery, textarea, selector, translate

I use [jQuery.translate](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-translate/), very normal code as:

```
$('body').translate(...
```

Now I do not want the `textarea` and `input:text` get translated, so I tried:

```
$('*:not(textarea,:text)').translate(..
$('body *:not(textarea, input:text)').translate(
```

None working.

(these answers got from another question: [jQuery, Select Body but exclude Textarea and Input:Text, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631078/jquery-select-body-but-exclude-textarea-and-inputtext-how)

Anyone here, has an idea how to translate the body but exclude textarea and input:text, thanks.

Comment: Ugh, just provide an english version and hire translators for languages your customers are likely to be interested in. Everything else will - at least when done automatically and not on explicit request - scare off people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the jQuery.translate wiki; first add the notranslate class to the elements you don't want to translate.

```
$('textarea').addClass('notranslate');
$('input:text').addClass('notranslate');
$('body').translate(...);
```

Comment: Hi there, can you show me the wiki that shows the "notranslate" class settings. Thanks

Comment: @EricYin, see [this page](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-translate/wiki/TranslateMethod), specifically the sec ion on "not" options.

Comment: Thanks but it's not working. I checked the source code, there no "notranslate" anyway :(. I am going to check the source code and see if I can change somewhere to get it work.

Answer (score 3):

A nice way to exclude elements from a selector is to use the [`.not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method:

```
$('*', document.body).not('textarea, input[type=text]').translate(...);
```

Comment: thanks. tried this, not working, I believe its not about the jQuery selector. There should have something to setup or change in jQuery.translate

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
$('body').translate( 'es', 'en', { not: 'textarea, input:text' });
```

(This is translating from Spanish to English, of course.)

Comment: I think I found a way to give a cssName and not: that cssName, works most case but some textarea in layers etc not work well. Still coding.